# Rails Association Help - Do I use Polymorphic Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, model-associations

I need help determining what kind of associations I should use for the following 3 models. Below are the tables and what I think the current association is. Please let me know if there is a better way to achieve below. Thanks

How the tables should look.

```
User Table
id

Meal Table
id

Comment Table
user_id
Meal_id
```

Here is what I think the associations look, but this may change depending on the type of association is used.

```
User
has_many :comments

Meal
has_many :comments

Comment
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :meal
```

Comment: As a follow up question. I am trying to write the controller to create a comment for a particular Meal and also link it to the User. I am following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, but they don't have a user and I'm not sure how to write it to the user_id column. If you could provide me with some example code that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That sound like a good way to do it.

I would rename the `belongs_to :user` association to `belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"` to be more explicit about the role the association plays in your system.

If you want to add more models to comment on, you should use [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).